# The $c$ in Ricci scalar in the RW metrc

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, cosmology

I was trying to find the Friedmann Equations from the EFE and I am confused about the "$c$" term coming from the Ricci scalar. I guess I am missing something simple, but I cannot find any good answer.

I'll use
$$T_{\mu\nu}=(\rho+P/c^2)U_{\mu}U_{\nu}-Pg_{\mu\nu}$$
for the perfect fluid, where in the rest frame becomes
$$T_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(\rho c^2, -Pg_{ij})$$
for
$U_{\mu}U_{\nu}=c^2.$

Notice that I did not omit $c$.

When I type the EFE, I find this
$$G_{00}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{00}=R_{00}-\frac{1}{2}g_{00}R$$
when $T_{00}=\rho c^2$, the LHS becomes
$$\frac{8\pi G}{c^2}\rho.$$
To obtain the known Friedmann equation that contains $c$, that is
$$\left(\frac{\dot{R}}{R}\right)^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho-\frac{kc^2}{R^2},$$ $R$ and $R_{\mu\nu}$ somehow contain $c$, (which is clear from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Equations)), but I know that the metric is
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(1,\frac{-R^2}{1-kr^2},-R^2r^2, -R^2r^2 \sin^2\theta).$$
I guess I am writing the metric wrong and it must somehow contain $c$, but I don't know where...

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1):

The time component of the metric does contain a factor of $c$. Namely, the metric of Minkowski spacetime, for example, is
$$g_{\mu\nu} \ \text{d}x^\mu \text{d}x^\nu = c^2 \text{d}t^2 - \text{d}x^2 - \text{d}y^2 - \text{d}z^2.$$

Notice that this is necessary for the units to be compatible.

Comment: So should I write the metric as, $$g_{\mu\nu}=\mathrm{diag}(c^2,\frac{-R^2}{1-kr^2},-R^2r^2, -R^2r^2 \sin^2\theta).$$

Comment: @Neptune precisely